# can't run r script from pycharm

Tags: r, pycharm, shebang

I am using pycharm with MAC, I am trying to execute R script even-though I have R compatibility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

lambda = 1.5
T=4
nsamp = 8
```

And I get the error:

> ```
> lambda = 1.5
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

How to fix it?

Comment: **How** are you trying to do this in PyCharm? While we have your R script, without more information on how you are trying to "execute" it, it may be hard to help.

Comment: @duckmayr I am just running it using the "play" button after I put the script path i the Run Configuration. The Python interpreter is set to 3.5 but since I put the shebang I thought it should handle the R script properly

Answer (score 1):

@okuoub, R support in PyCharm is possible by using the 'R Language Support' plugin. 
From PyCharm, go to:

> Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace'

Search for 'R Language Support. Install it, restart PyCharm.

Next, go to

> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> R Language

Add the path to the R interpreter (install R, if it's not already on your machine).
Then go to

> File -> New

Choose R script and have fun!